# Is every tessellation of the plane into convex polygons a Voronoi tessellation?

Tags: discrete-geometry, voronoi-diagram

Given an arbitrary tessellation of the two-dim. plane into convex polygons, can one show that this is *always* a Voronoi tessalation, *without* knowing the points that would define the Voronoi tessellation?

If this is not the case, what are the sufficient conditions that a given tessellation into convex polygons is a Voronoi tessellation?

Thanks

Comment: If you start with the infinite square grid with vertices at $\Bbb Z^2$, and then, for every $a,b\in \Bbb Z$, you replace the four squares with a vertex at $(4a,4b)$ with a single square of side-length $2$, the resulting tesselation is not Voronoi.

Comment: No, tessellations of convex polygons are not always Voronoi tessellations. If you want an example, consider a large regular polygon surrounded by very small-diameter polygons. Points in the regular polygon near the boundary will be very close to some of the small polygons. This makes the placement of a point for the large regular polygon impossible. I can't answer your other question though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can anybody answer the second question re sufficient conditions? except for the trivial one that „there exist points for which the Voronoi-condition holds“.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't simple, easy to state sufficient conditions. But this question has been studied pretty thoroughly in [this paper](https://www.cs.umb.edu/%7Eeb/dirichlet/RecognizingDTs.pdf):

*Ash, Peter F.; Bolker, Ethan D.*, [**Recognizing Dirichlet tesselations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00181470), Geom. Dedicata 19, 175-206 (1985). [ZBL0572.52022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0572.52022).

The authors summarize this as:

> To decide whether a given tessellation is a Dirichlet tessellation requires two steps: a local argument at each vertex and a pasting mechanism.

Given a tessellation, the generally describe a locally conclude that a tessellation is not Voronoi (or Dirichlet in their terminology). But things become especially complex to handle cases where the [Voronoi sites cannot be determined from the tessellation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160746/equality-of-voronoi-diagram/3646619).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Ethan Bolker is an [MSE contributor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72858/ethan-bolker)!